# Using stripslashes after mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql

I have to escape some inputs on a form. I used mysql_real_escape_string to escape the value but it adds a lot slashes with value inside database, the reason is i have an apostrophe in my input let us say exp's.

Now to get rid of slashes, I use stripslashes after mysql_real_escape_string and then data goes to database successfully and don't see any apostrophe with value in database.

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['userame']));
$name = stripslashes(stripslashes($userame));
```

// then data goes to db successfully without apostrophe

I just wanted to confirm, is this correct way of escaping the input value? Thanks

Dayan

Comment: I suppose you're using backslashes\ instead of slashes/ ? Because that's used for escaping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Disabling Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)
2. `mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['username']));`

Answer (score 2):

No it's not. Check your php.ini for the [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) setting. If you can't disable it use stripslashes BEFORE using `mysql_real_escape_string`. The link has a method to strip it globally from `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE`. Or even better, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you have magic_quotes_gpc enabled you should use the stripslashes() function before escaping - otherwise you will escape twice, thus loads of slashes.

http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php