# What is stripslashes for?

Tags: php, mysql, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using stripslashes after mysql_real_escape_string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295141/using-stripslashes-after-mysql-real-escape-string)

I have been reading most recently about prevention of SQL injection and I am trying to develop some sense of understanding between the different functions so that I can learn the basics.

I have read about `mysql_real_escape_string` and I understand that it is basically escaping characters which it deems "special" so that it is not confused for SQL syntax?

Now, assuming that is at least to some degree true - is there a need to use the `stripslashes` function combined with the `mysql_real_escape_string`? I'm wondering about what `stripslashes` is and what it is for.

Comment: That function is called [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.stripslashes.php). And yes, the usefulness of `mysql_real_escape_string` is "real". And no, you shouldn't need to use it with `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I have written wrong - thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I can't find a `striphashes` function in the PHP documentation. Do you mean `stripslashes`? Also, `mysql_real_escape_string` is used to escape anything that is potentially SQL in such a way that it is no longer SQL. The scenario is: you get string data from a user; you want to user this data in an SQL statement; using `mysql_real_escape_string` ensures that the user can't insert SQL into their data. AKA, [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) prevention.

Comment: I think it's a good question: What, in reality, is `stripslashes` useful for? Every time I've seen it used it either shouldn't be or didn't have to be. Is it just for dealing with magic quotes?

Comment: Yeah, mainly manual material. The SQL context given with this question can only be used to raise the flag and pointing to prepared statements (parametrized queries), telling the OP that `mysql_real_escape_string` is deprecated. Not saying it's a bad question, but I don't find it particularly good either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use `stripslashes` on input right after using `mysql_real_escape_string`, you will effectively undo it.  There are probably other reasons to use `stripslashes`, but in my case I have only ever needed it to undo the horror that is magic quotes.  It's actually the opposite of `addslashes`.

`addslashes` does *not necessarily* escape input the same as `mysql_real_escape_string` does, and they cannot be used for the same purpose.

Even better than `mysql_*`, you should read up on using prepared statements like in [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php).  Then you don't even have to worry about `mysql_*` or `stripslashes` (except for magic quotes).

Comment: Thanks I think I understand it now, will chose as answer when I can.

Comment: You can't learn too much about [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: I'd like to point out that some (all?) implementations of `mysql_real_escape_string` escape quotes by doubling them: `mysql_real_escape_string("don't")` effectively returns `"don''t"`, so using `stripslashes` won't undo it. It's still not productive to call `stripslashes` on the output of `mysql_real_escape_string`, though; but don't expect it to revert your string to its original state.

Comment: @tadman The link has changed: http://bobby-tables.com/php.html

Answer (score 4):

The function [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/stripslashes) will unescape characters that are escaped with a backslash, `\`. It is commonly used on strings that are escaped via [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/addslashes), or if your PHP configuration has [`magic_quotes`](http://php.net/magic_quotes) enabled.

When using SQL-escaping functions such as [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string), there is no need to use `stripslashes()` because the MySQL-adapter will only escape the values on insertion into the database - the slashes will not remain in the actual values. If you were to use `stripslashes()` on a variable that you already escaped with `mysql_real_escape_string()`, it will remove the slashes as if it were escaped using `addslashes()` - fairly pointless though.

If your goal is to prevent SQL-Injection, I would highly recommend looking into [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) opposed to the older `mysql_` methods. Both MySQLi and PDO offer prepared-statements which, if used properly, will prevent SQL-Injection without the need to remember calling special escaping functions *or* worrying if your data will be modified from them.

Answer (score 1):

stripslashes function is used for `Un-quotes a quoted string`

Example :

```
<?php
echo stripslashes("how\'s going on?");
?>
```

The output of the code above will be:

```
how's going on?
```

For more details:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: Stripslashes is not unquoting a quoted string. That sounds pretty wrong worded in my ears. Also your example is not of much use.

Comment: @hakre to be fair, this is exactly the way it's described in the PHP manual....

Comment: @Martin: You're correct, back in 2012 my understanding of quoting most likely was limited, English is not my first language.

Answer (score 1):

check out

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

The escape functions add slashes '\' to escape characters that can be used to terminate valid query STRINGS (not the query itself) to prevent injection. the stripslashes function is used to remove these slashes, however there's no practical use for them in building query strings as they remove the needed slashes.

Results from MySQL are not 'slashed' (escaped) so stripslashes it isn't needed when dealing with results.